# Reload/redirect page from included php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, http-redirect

My application has the following structure:

**main.php**
it includes the config.php that has the credentials to the database.

**page1.php**
wich also includes the config.php and calls get_page1_content.php through AJAX.

**get_page1_content.php**
wich also includes the config.php and is called through ajax every time page1.php needs.

My url is allways www.mysite.com/main.php and I load all the pagesX.php files through JavaScript.

example of page1.php, get_page1_content.php and main.php first lines:

```
include("config.php");
$conf=new config();
```

I want to check if the php session is UP and if it's not I want to refresh the page.
Problem is that all my files include the config.php

for now in config.php I have the following __construct()function:

```
    if (isset($_SESSION['@ADMIN'])){
        $result=true;
    }
    else {
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0\">";
    }
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I can see i get the  tag to refresh in response to get_page1_content.php but the browser doesn't refresh.

Is my architecture wrong? How can I fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I had a lot of ajax going on, I've added this function that is called every time ther is an AJAX error.

```
// Deal with ajax calls errors        
$( document ).ajaxError(function(e) {
    if ($.cookie('sitecookie')!=null){
        console.log("cookie exists");
        console.log($.cookie('sitecookie'));
        console.log(e);
    } else {
        alert("Your session expired. Please log in again.");
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the page with this :

```
   $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
   $sec = "0";
   header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
```

This will refresh the page every 0 seconds , So , if you **if** condition is true , then the page refreshes

Comment: That code sends a header to refresh the php file that last called the config.php. So with that i get a request header: Refresh:0; url=/beta/v4/adm/inc/get_page1_content.php
And it doesn't refresh my main.php

Comment: header("Refresh:0");
what if now ?

Comment: I just mimicked your structure and tested it , it works fine by me ,

Comment: I've updated my question. The call to the get_page1_content.php is through AJAX. Maybe some code to run if AJAX get's an error?

Comment: ajax with jquery or ajax with javascript ? 
you can search on google :(

Comment: add  header("location:index.php"); after $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

Answer (score 0):

You can check the session in your `get_page1_content.php` and return an error message if the session is expired. In your AJAX script, check for an error and use `document.location.reload(true)` if necessary. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload for more information.